# Is there a way to get `git stash pop` to skip the status report?

Tags: git

When I do `git stash pop` it takes a long time, and then I get the same output as from `git status` which usually has this warning at the end:

```
It took 69.96 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
```

Is there a way of making `git stash pop` skip this part? I know I have a load of untracked files, and I don't need git to spend time listing them for me.

Comment: have you tried `git stash pop --quiet`?

Comment: No, I hadn't! Looks good, but will it say something if the stash pop causes a conflict? The docs don't say.

Comment: @joachim Please do an experiment and tell us. :-)

Comment: The docs say pretty clear: "no feedback is provided". It's either quiet or not. But I figure you might pipe git with sed/awk to filter out stuff and print only what you want to print. No performance increase though...

Comment: I don't think that's clear -- does 'feedback' mean 'helpful information' or 'also errors'? I don't know! @phd will do!

Comment: Ok I don't know WHAT happened, but I tried it, and ended up with git status claiming all my files were deleted while also saying that the subfolders were untracked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `--quiet` option. Although [its description](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt---quiet) (*“Quiet, suppress feedback messages.”*) isn’t very clear, it does suppress the `status` part of the output.

#### Example with conflicts

```
$ git stash pop --quiet 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        foo
        bar
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
$
```

#### Example with mergeable conflicts

```
$ git stash pop --quiet 
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
$
```